# Find missing rows in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please help me to fix the below issues,
I have below table, A column is the quarter no and b as the currency and c as amount column.
For e.g. quarter 1 has 1, 2 &3 currency, but quarter 2 and 3 has 2 &3 and 3 currency only. In this scenario I want to find out missing currency and insert the previous quarter amount.

```
 Quarter  currency Amount    
1   1   45.000
1   2   425.000
1   3   145.000
3   2   400.000
3   3   145.000
4   3   145.000
```

Output:

```
   Quarter  currency Amount 
1   1   45.000
1   2   425.000
1   3   145.000
2   1   45.000
2   2   425.000
2   3   145.000
3   1   45.000
3   2   425.000
3   3   145.000
4   1   45.000
4   2   425.000
4   3   145.000
```

Quarter is sequences number, Some quarter is not present in the sequence want to copy previous quarter values and While doing we have to check if missing quarter previous and next quarter should be available.

Answer (score 2):

This has two important pieces to it.  The first is getting the right rows out.  You can do that with a `cross join`.  Then you need to get the previous quarter's value.  Here is one method for that, using a correlated subquery:

```
select q.quarter, c.currency,
       (select top 1 amount
        from table t
        where t.currency = c.currency and t.quarter <= q.quarter
        order by quarter desc
       ) amount
from (select distinct quarter from table) q cross join
     (select distinct currency from table) c;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!! Quarter is sequences number, Some quarter is not present in the sequence want to copy previous quarter values and While doing we have to check if missing quarter previous and next quarter should be available.

Comment: @jay . . . I believe the above query answers the question that you asked.  If you have another question, then it might be better to ask another question.